# Script for initializing JQuery Masonry for Wordpress

Tags: jquery

What is the different between this (http://pastebin.com/PX0YB0hy) and (http://pastebin.com/VBqiMHVQ) for JQuery Masonry.

Why does the first one work and the second one doesn't.

In both cases I used wp_enqueue_script to add the script.

Thanks!

Comment: And - did that explain the difference?

Comment: Glad it helped. These three functions are our best jQuery friends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This executes, when the DOM has been constructed, before all content has been loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
$(function(){...}); // short form
```

This executes, when all content has been loaded

```
$(window).load(function(){ ... });
```

This executes immediately, when it is first encountered by the browser

```
(function(){ ... })();
```

The latter is known as a self-executing anonymous function, which is very handy, but not here, because no content or not the right content may have been loaded when it self-executes.